# Slow views problem and duplicate content

Tags: 7, views

I'm building a news community with Drupal. I've overcome the most difficult things but I'm stuck on a bad view. Practically I created a user field called "interests" where you enter some tags describing your interests (such as Obama, Wars, Technology and so on). So I've created a view called "My news" where it fetches the "interests" user field and then load content containing the fetched tags (for example if the tags I entered were cats and Obama, then only content about Obama and cats will show in "My News"). The problem initially was that i would get everything right, but then I would also get many duplicates like this:

```
Obama reaches an accord with Germany
Obama reaches an accord with Germany
The hero cat who saved this guy
The hero cat who saved this guy
Obama reaches an accord with Germany
```

instead of:

```
Obama reaches an accord with Germany
The hero cat who saved this guy
```

To remedy this I checked aggregation and I finally had unique results, but I suspect it slows down the view..
For just 2 articles it takes more than 300ms to render the view.
The second problem is that it won't show the rate widget, only if I select the default appearance, but it only displays numbers, no arrows. Well you could say 'no big deal, it still shows the votes', but I'll number the content and they shouldn't be confused with the actual votes (something like Reddit).

This is the exported view:

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'user';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'user';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'My content';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['group_by'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'mini';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['id'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'table';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['columns'] = array(
  'title' => 'title',
  'comment_count' => 'comment_count',
);
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['default'] = '-1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['info'] = array(
  'title' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'comment_count' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
);
/* Relationship: Content: Author */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['id'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['field'] = 'uid';
/* Relationship: User: interests (field_interests) */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['field_interests_tid']['id'] = 'field_interests_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['field_interests_tid']['table'] = 'field_data_field_interests';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['field_interests_tid']['field'] = 'field_interests_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['field_interests_tid']['relationship'] = 'uid';
/* Relationship: Taxonomy term: Content using tags */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['reverse_field_tags_node']['id'] = 'reverse_field_tags_node';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['reverse_field_tags_node']['table'] = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['reverse_field_tags_node']['field'] = 'reverse_field_tags_node';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['reverse_field_tags_node']['relationship'] = 'field_interests_tid';
/* Relationship: Content: Vote results */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['votingapi_cache']['id'] = 'votingapi_cache';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['votingapi_cache']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['votingapi_cache']['field'] = 'votingapi_cache';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['votingapi_cache']['relationship'] = 'reverse_field_tags_node';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['votingapi_cache']['votingapi'] = array(
  'value_type' => 'points',
  'tag' => 'vote',
  'function' => 'sum',
);
/* Field: Vote results: Value */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['value']['id'] = 'value';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['value']['table'] = 'votingapi_cache';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['value']['field'] = 'value';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['value']['relationship'] = 'votingapi_cache';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['value']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['value']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['value']['precision'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['value']['appearance'] = 'rate_views_widget_compact_disabled';
/* Field: Content: picture */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_picture']['id'] = 'field_picture';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_picture']['table'] = 'field_data_field_picture';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_picture']['field'] = 'field_picture';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_picture']['relationship'] = 'reverse_field_tags_node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_picture']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_picture']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_picture']['click_sort_column'] = 'fid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_picture']['settings'] = array(
  'image_style' => 'real-thumbnail',
  'image_link' => 'file',
);
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_picture']['group_column'] = 'entity_id';
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['relationship'] = 'reverse_field_tags_node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['text'] = '[created]';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Post date */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['relationship'] = 'reverse_field_tags_node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['alter']['alter_text'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['alter']['text'] = 'Submitted [created]';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['date_format'] = 'time ago';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['custom_date_format'] = '1';
/* Field: User: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['relationship'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['alter_text'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['text'] = 'by [name] in';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: tags */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_tags']['id'] = 'field_tags';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_tags']['table'] = 'field_data_field_tags';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_tags']['field'] = 'field_tags';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_tags']['relationship'] = 'reverse_field_tags_node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_tags']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_tags']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_tags']['delta_offset'] = '0';
/* Field: Content: Nid */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['id'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['field'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['relationship'] = 'reverse_field_tags_node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Comment count */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count']['id'] = 'comment_count';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count']['table'] = 'node_comment_statistics';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count']['field'] = 'comment_count';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count']['relationship'] = 'reverse_field_tags_node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count']['alter']['make_link'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count']['alter']['path'] = 'node/[nid]/#comments';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count']['alter']['absolute'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count']['format_plural'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count']['format_plural_singular'] = '1 comment';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count']['format_plural_plural'] = '@count comments';
/* Sort criterion: COUNT(DISTINCT Vote results: Value) */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['value']['id'] = 'value';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['value']['table'] = 'votingapi_cache';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['value']['field'] = 'value';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['value']['relationship'] = 'votingapi_cache';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['value']['group_type'] = 'count_distinct';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['value']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Filter criterion: COUNT(DISTINCT Content: Published) */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['relationship'] = 'reverse_field_tags_node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group_type'] = 'count_distinct';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value']['min'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value']['max'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value']['value'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'mypage';
```

This the query executed:

```
SELECT votingapi_cache_node_points_vote_sum.value AS votingapi_cache_node_points_vote_sum_value, field_tags_taxonomy_term_data.title AS field_tags_taxonomy_term_data_title, field_tags_taxonomy_term_data.nid AS field_tags_taxonomy_term_data_nid_1, field_tags_taxonomy_term_data.created AS field_tags_taxonomy_term_data_created, users_node.name AS users_node_name, users_node.uid AS users_node_uid, field_tags_taxonomy_term_data__field_data_field_tags.field_tags_tid AS field_tags_taxonomy_term_data__field_data_field_tags_field_t, field_tags_taxonomy_term_data__node_comment_statistics.comment_count AS field_tags_taxonomy_term_data__node_comment_statistics_comme, MIN(field_tags_taxonomy_term_data.nid) AS field_tags_taxonomy_term_data_nid, 'node' AS field_data_field_picture_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_tags_node_entity_type, COUNT(DISTINCT votingapi_cache_node_points_vote_sum.value) AS votingapi_cache_node_points_vote_sum_value_1
FROM 
{node} node
LEFT JOIN {users} users_node ON node.uid = users_node.uid
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_interests} users_node__field_data_field_interests ON users_node.uid = users_node__field_data_field_interests.entity_id AND (users_node__field_data_field_interests.entity_type = 'user' AND users_node__field_data_field_interests.deleted = '0')
LEFT JOIN {taxonomy_term_data} taxonomy_term_data_field_data_field_interests ON users_node__field_data_field_interests.field_interests_tid = taxonomy_term_data_field_data_field_interests.tid
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_tags} taxonomy_term_data_field_data_field_interests__field_data_field_tags ON taxonomy_term_data_field_data_field_interests.tid = taxonomy_term_data_field_data_field_interests__field_data_field_tags.field_tags_tid AND (taxonomy_term_data_field_data_field_interests__field_data_field_tags.entity_type = 'node' AND taxonomy_term_data_field_data_field_interests__field_data_field_tags.deleted = '0')
LEFT JOIN {node} field_tags_taxonomy_term_data ON taxonomy_term_data_field_data_field_interests__field_data_field_tags.entity_id = field_tags_taxonomy_term_data.nid
LEFT JOIN {votingapi_cache} votingapi_cache_node_points_vote_sum ON field_tags_taxonomy_term_data.nid = votingapi_cache_node_points_vote_sum.entity_id AND (votingapi_cache_node_points_vote_sum.entity_type = 'node' AND votingapi_cache_node_points_vote_sum.value_type = 'points' AND votingapi_cache_node_points_vote_sum.tag = 'vote' AND votingapi_cache_node_points_vote_sum.function = 'sum')
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_picture} field_tags_taxonomy_term_data__field_data_field_picture ON field_tags_taxonomy_term_data.nid = field_tags_taxonomy_term_data__field_data_field_picture.entity_id AND (field_tags_taxonomy_term_data__field_data_field_picture.entity_type = 'node' AND field_tags_taxonomy_term_data__field_data_field_picture.deleted = '0')
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_tags} field_tags_taxonomy_term_data__field_data_field_tags ON field_tags_taxonomy_term_data.nid = field_tags_taxonomy_term_data__field_data_field_tags.entity_id AND (field_tags_taxonomy_term_data__field_data_field_tags.entity_type = 'node' AND field_tags_taxonomy_term_data__field_data_field_tags.deleted = '0')
INNER JOIN {node_comment_statistics} field_tags_taxonomy_term_data__node_comment_statistics ON field_tags_taxonomy_term_data.nid = field_tags_taxonomy_term_data__node_comment_statistics.nid
GROUP BY votingapi_cache_node_points_vote_sum_value, field_data_field_picture_node_entity_type, field_tags_taxonomy_term_data_title, field_tags_taxonomy_term_data_nid_1, field_tags_taxonomy_term_data_created, users_node_name, users_node_uid, field_data_field_tags_node_entity_type, field_tags_taxonomy_term_data__field_data_field_tags_field_t, field_tags_taxonomy_term_data__node_comment_statistics_comme
HAVING (( (COUNT(DISTINCT field_tags_taxonomy_term_data.status) = '1') ))
ORDER BY votingapi_cache_node_points_vote_sum_value_1 DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

And these the loading specifics of the view:

```
Query build time    3.51 ms
Query execute time  1.39 ms
View render time    300.18 ms
```

Thank you by now for any help, I'm pulling my hair trying to solve this!!

Comment: By looking at the query I think that the COUNT DISTINCT at last and the many LEFT JOIN's could be the culprit here?

Comment: Do you need to use aggregation to get distinct results? There is a distinct setting hidden under advanced->other->query settings, though I'm not sure it will help. I also have heard that using the pager can slow things down a bit.

Comment: The query times are reasonable; there is an option in Views to turn on and show the additional queries Views executes to actually render the View.  If you go to `admin/structure/views/settings` and click on `Show other queries run during render during live preview` you will see these when you preview your View again; and that's most probably where you will see the real culprits.

Comment: I did that and ended up choosing the default vote widget faking the vote arrows. The query rendering time got down to ~10ms after doing that, so the culprit here was the vote thing.